# Unstable high-pass filter on mouse-generated signal

Tags: python, filter-design, digital-filters, scipy, highpass-filter

I am making a Desktop application using PyQT as the app is a Digital Filter
You can add zeros and poles to a unit circle and apply the filter to the data
the data can be of two types
1- saved data on the pc that you can open (CSV file)
2- generated signal using a mouse movement on a pad and here is the UI of the app
[image: Digital Filter App UI]

normally I can make a high-pass filter and apply it to the signal and the signal works well
for the uploaded signals
but when I make a high pass filter to a mouse-generated signal I encounter something strange happening, there is a zigzag added to the filtered data
[image: High Pass zigzag]
this zigzag pattern is added only at a high-pass filter with a generated signal with the mouse. It doesn't appear at loss pass with the mouse or at any filter with saved data. only mouse-generated signal with high-pass.
I don't understand what is the problem as the filter works well at everything except that

Can anyone just refer to what the reason may be to learn it and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

(I thought I answered this before, but here we go again).

The impulse response of your filter has a lot of ringing since the pole is very close to the unit circle. It looks like this.

[image]

Every time you have a discontinuity in the signal itself or its derivative, you trigger either the step response (which looks similar) or the impulse response itself. Hence this type of ringing is called "transient response". This happens  both at the beginning of your signal and at around sample 130 (where you have a strong discontinuity of the derivative).

The answer is correct for the input signal. Turns out that signals drawn by hand are not particularly well behaved and don't look like anything you would typically see in nature.

Comment: yeah you answered this question for my friend in college
we have the same problem kinda
but in his code, the zig-zag only appears at the beginning
but mine the zigzag appears along the signal to the end

so how can I make a real high pass filter that works well and doesn't have these zigzags?

Are there certain zeros, poles coordinates I should use

Comment: The zig zags are real. Your high pass filter works as intended. What's the problem ?

Comment: ok, thanks for your time. I understood your answer wrong at first but now I get it